# How can I run single tests?

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js, browserify, mocha-phantomjs

in my `Gruntfile.js` I have the following:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    remove: {
        default_options: {
            trace: false,
            fileList: [
                'tests/browser/libs.js',
                'tests/browser/tests.js'
            ]   
        }   
    },  
    browserify: {
        test: {
            src: ['src/*.js', 'tests/browser/editor.js'],
            dest: 'tests/browser/single.js'
        },  
        tests: {
            src: ['tests/browser/*.js'],
            dest: 'tests/browser/tests.js'
        },  
        libs: {
            src: ['src/*.js'],
            dest: 'tests/browser/libs.js'
        }   
    },  
    mocha_phantomjs: {
        all: ['tests/browser/*.html']
        , single: ['tests/browser/single.html']
    }   
  }); 

  grunt.registerTask('test-x', ['remove', 'browserify:test', 'mocha_phantomjs:single']);
  grunt.registerTask('test-web', ['remove', 'browserify', 'mocha_phantomjs']);
```

where the idea is that I should either be able to run all tests, or run a specific test file... but I have issues with it:

> $ grunt test-web
>
> Running "remove:default_options"
>   (remove) task
>
> Running "browserify:test" (browserify) task
>   Bundle tests/browser/single.js created.
>
> Running "browserify:tests" (browserify) task
>   Error: Cannot find module './lib/chai' from '/Users/ekkis/Development/tst/tests/browser' Warning: Error running
>   grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

and I think the problem is that when I run 'browserify' in the 'test-web' definition, it runs 'test', in addition to 'tests' and 'libs'.  so what (I think) I need is a way to run `browserify:tests & libs`.

is that possible? how does everyone else deal with the fact that sometimes one wants to run just one test file?

TIA - e

Comment: Can you run "npm install --save-dev chai" ... and retry? I think you load "chai" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) on your tests but is not installed

Comment: it's installed.  I haven't gotten to the bottom of why that message but it's installed

Answer (score 0):

figured out I can just have multiple steps:

```
grunt.registerTask('test-web', ['remove', 'browserify:tests', 'browserify:libs', 'mocha_phantomjs']);
```